# Plugin development - Querying related data

Tags: plugin-development, relations, models, query

I am working on a Craft plugin.

I have a main entities are 'Courses' and 'Entries'. If I click on an Entries in the CMS there is an option to select and associated 'Course'.

In my controller I can get a Course as follows:

```
$course = craft()->entries->getEntryById($variables['pathId']);
```

So far so good, but now I want to get all related 'Entries', so I do the following:

```
$entries=$course->entries->find();
```

This gives the following error:

```
Property "Craft\EntryModel.entries" is not defined.
```

What am I doing wrong? Clearly the two are related so why isn't this method working?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this works but is it an acceptable solution:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'checkin';

$criteria->relatedTo = array(
     'targetElement' => $entry,
     'field' => $field
);

$checkin = craft()->elements->findElements($criteria);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for

```
$criteria->with = array('fieldHandle');
```